# terminate simple python server wont shut down with ctrl + C

Tags: python, terminal, zsh, simplehttpserver

I ran a simple web server using

```
python -m simpleHTTPServer 8888 &.
```

it starts well. Then used ctrl+C to attempt to terminate it, and I go to

```
http://localhost:8888/
```

and the server is still running. Am I doing something wrong?

I am using zsh for terminal, not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s because of the `&` that causes the command to be run in background.  After you started the process, you get the process id. Using that id, you can `kill` the process:

```
$ python &
[1] 5050
$ kill -15 5050
[1]+  Angehalten              python
```

If sending a `SIGTERM` signal (`-15`) does not work, you can use `SIGKILL` (`-9`).

*Edited to use `SIGTERM` instead of `SIGKILL`, see @starrify’s comment.*

Comment: ..+1ed and then cancelled. Can't we first try something soft like SIGTERM? SIGKILL is somehow brute, although it might be totally fine in this case.

Comment: Isn't it also possible to `fg` into python and then ctrl-c it?

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL+C` sends `SIGINT`. You should send a kill signal using `kill -9 pid` to kill the process

Comment: -1 for there's actually no `SIGINT` sent to the OP's process.

Comment: zomg!sorry, I should read more carefully, I did not even see the tiny & in the end of the statement. Apologies

Comment: Well I'm sorry but StackOverflow prevents me from cancelling the down vote >_<!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you need `&.` here. However in most of the shells (of course zsh is included) the symbol `&` mean `to start this task in the background`, which means your `CTRL+C` is actually not received by the application.

Try remove the `&.` and see what would happen.

**EDITED:** See @RobinKrahl's answer for how to terminate the process by sending a signal to it using `kill`. However for terminating a finely working process I suggest use `SIGTERM` (signal number 15) instead of `SIGKILL` (signal number 9).

Answer (score 0):

It's because of &. It is now a background process which you cannot kill by ctrl+c.

As it is server, I recommend you to use &. To kill off the server, do -> ps aux | grep simpleHTTPServer to find the process id and then do kill -9 pid

Comment: doing that gives me   501  5200  1141   0  2:42PM ttys002    0:00.00 grep simpleHTTPServer. are "501  5200  1141   0" all separate processing running?

Comment: Updated. Use ps aux instead of ps -ef. The first number is the pid. Also u should look for your command in the output. Right now it looks that the server is already killed. When you do a grep, that command is also part of the process listed in ps aux output (which is the case with you right now).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: If sending a `SIGKILL` doesn't work, as a last resort try `killall python`

I ran into a similar problem in which the localhost server would simply change to another pid even after I gave it a `SIGKILL`. The only thing that worked for me, and would probably work as a last resort for anyone else experiencing this would be to simply run in bash: `killall python`.